# How to fix Ruby Rack SessionId error Error: undefined class/module Rack::Session::SessionId when decoding the rack.session cookie

Tags: ruby, rack

While writing a ruby script to decode rack session cookies and load the object using the ruby function Marshal load, I am getting the following error:

> Error: undefined class/module Rack::Session::SessionId

This is my ruby script:

```
require 'pp'
require 'base64'
require 'uri'
require 'rack' # solves the error: Error: undefined class/module Rack::

c = gets
cookie, signature = c.split("--")
decoded = Base64.decode64(URI.decode(cookie))
begin
    object = Marshal.load(decoded)
    pp object
rescue ArgumentError => e
    puts "Error: " + e.to_s
end
```

How do I fix this? I tried looking for solutions on stackoverflow but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Louis Nyffenegger (@snyff)](https://twitter.com/snyff) who helped me with this
https://twitter.com/snyff/status/1407054131697758211?s=20

This error can be solved by creating a [method stub](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rspec/rspec_stubs.htm)

```
require 'pp'
require 'base64'
require 'uri'
require 'rack'

class Rack::Session::SessionId
end

c = gets
cookie, signature = c.split("--")
decoded = Base64.decode64(URI.decode(cookie))
begin
    object = Marshal.load(decoded)
    pp object
rescue ArgumentError => e
    puts "Error: " + e.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all of the cookies for the site.

I think this works because something is causing an exception while loading the Rack::Session::SessionId class.

This type of error happens occasionally when working on Rails applications. A SyntaxError (or any other exception) inside a class definition (e.g. in a model) can then cause an undefined class/module error instead of the real error.